# What is log_write_percent in Azure SQL Server?

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

We are running some databases on Azure SQL Server and have monitoring set up on them. We do a lot of reads and writes and are receiving a lot of messages that log_write_percent is > 90%. What exactly is log_write_percent measuring? Is that telling us that our log files are at 90% of their maximum size? Does Azure SQL Server have some throughput limit for logs that we're bumping up against? Is it something else?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Azure SQL Database log file is limited to 48 MBps. When you see log_write_percent above 90% then throttling is most probably occurring.

The avg_log_write_percent is the average write I/O throughput utilization as percentage of the limit of the service tier.